# How to check that c99 is used, and not gnu99

Tags: gcc, gnu, c99

I want to add a warning message during the compilation to warn the user it should use gnu99 instead of c99 (I am using anonymous struct, and it seems it doesn't exist at all in c99).

I found that:

```
#if __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L
```

but this test is true for c99 and gnu99.

Which predefined macro could I use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check for yourself:

```
$ gcc -std=c99 -dM -E - < /dev/null > c99.txt
$ gcc -std=gnu99 -dM -E - < /dev/null > gnu99.txt
$ sdiff -s c99.txt gnu99.txt
#define __STRICT_ANSI__ 1                     <
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll play more with gcc next time.

Comment: No problem - I would have given you a more definitive answer but I'm away from home right now without access to a machine with gcc on it

Comment: `__STRICT_ANSI__` would be that one.